# Thread safety on HashMap.toString() method

Tags: java, thread-safety, hashmap, tostring

I have following piece of code :

```
public Hashmap<String,String> tempmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

and a class function :

```
void f1(){
    synchronized(onClassVariable1){
    ....Some code onClassVariable1...
    String tempString = tempMap.toString();
    ... Some work onClassVarible1 and tempString ...
    }
  }
```

Multiple thread call this function f1 through an object of this class ..

is this function thread-safe ??

Comment: You could use `Collections.synchronizedMap(tempmap)` to get a thread-safe map.

Comment: Note that you should make synchronized block as short as possible. After you are done with tempMap, exit the block and you can do any processing on the string outside the block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on whether there are methods which don't synchronize on `onClassVariable1` and modify `tempMap`.

Comment: To clarify, for `onClassVariable1` to be thread safe, all writes to the map must occur inside synchronized blocks (that synchronize on the same object).  For example, Thread-A & Thread-B calling `f1` simultaneously cannot enter the synchronized block inside `f1` at the same time.  However, suppose you have another function `f2` in another class that modifies `onClassVariable1` outside of any synchronized block.  Then, a Thread-C can modify the HashMap whilst another Thread is inside the synced block in `f1`

Answer (score 1):

*Nothing* in `HashMap` is thread-safe, and the Javadoc says so: "If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. "